# how to put different C strings in a pretty format?

Tags: c++, string, io, formatting

I am writing a simple program that builds a directory index of the current directory.

Each file has two char* objects for file name and last-modified time, and one integer for the file size.

I want to put all these in one big `string` or `char*`.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

char* file_info(char*);
int main(void)
{
  DIR           *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  d = opendir(".");
  if (d)
  {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
      file_info(dir->d_name);
    }

    closedir(d);
  }

  return(0);
}

char* file_info(char* file) {
    if(file[0] != '.') {
        struct stat sb;

        if (stat(file, &sb) == -1) {
            perror("stat");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char* lm = ctime(&sb.st_mtime);
        *lm = '\0';
        stringstream ss;
        ss << file << "           " << lm << "           " << sb.st_size;

        cout << ss.str() << endl;
    }
    return lm;
}
```

I want the returned `char*` to be an object that has content in this format:

```
homework-1.pdf   12-Sep-2013  10:57   123K    
homework-2.pdf   03-Oct-2013  13:58   189K  
hw1_soln.pdf     24-Sep-2013  10:36   178K  
hw2_soln.pdf     14-Oct-2013  09:37   655K
```

The spacing is the major issue here.
How can I correct it easily?
My attempt so far was

```
const char* file_info(char* file) {
    if(file[0] != '.') {
        struct stat sb;

        if (stat(file, &sb) == -1) {
            perror("stat");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char* lm = ctime(&sb.st_mtime);
        string lastmod(lm);
        lastmod.at(lastmod.size()-1) = '\0';
        stringstream ss;
        string spacing = "                                       ";
        ss << file << spacing.substr(0, spacing.size() - sizeof(file)) << lastmod << spacing.substr(0, spacing.size() - lastmod.size()) << sb.st_size;

        cout << ss.str() << endl;

        return ss.str().c_str();
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

but it did not work, and I worked with strings so poorly.

Comment: Don’t return `char const*` for the love of rightfold. Return `std::string`.

Comment: This is C++, not C.  You should probably change the title to reflect that.

Comment: Rather than try and compose a whole string with each iteration, populate a struct with each field (name, date/time, size) and put them in a vector.  Then iterate over the vector saving the largest size of each field.  Then you know the largest size of each field and you can format the lines so they are aligned and spaced correctly on a second pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.

However, none of them worked as I intended.(especially, it's not for outputting, but for making a string object.)

I ended up achieving what I wanted, but it's by no means good.

I attach my program, though, below. Feel free to comment.

Thank you.

```
void file_info(char*, stringstream&);

int main(void)
{
  DIR           *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  d = opendir(".");
  stringstream ss;
  if (d)
  {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
      file_info(dir->d_name, ss);
    }

    closedir(d);
  }
  cout << ss.str() << endl;
  return(0);
}

void file_info(char* file, stringstream& ss) {
    if(file[0] != '.') {
        struct stat sb;

        if (stat(file, &sb) == -1) {
            perror("stat");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char* lm = ctime(&sb.st_mtime);
        string lastmod(lm);
        lastmod.at(lastmod.size()-1) = '\0';
        string spacing = "                                  ";
        ss << file << spacing.substr(0, spacing.size() - strlen(file)) << lastmod << spacing.substr(0, spacing.size() - lastmod.size()) << sb.st_size << '\n';

    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem:

```
// ...
stringstream ss;
// ...
return ss.str().c_str(); // woops! ss goes out of scope and string will be destroyed!
```

This can be easily solved by making your function return `std::string` instead of `char const*` and doing this:

```
return ss.str();
```

There is no reason to return `char const*` here. It complicates everything, requires manual memory management, *will be* exception-unsafe at some point, confuses people who call your function and makes your code utterly unmaintainable.

Comment: I need it to be C string. It has to be passed to send() function. By the way, is there any better way to do this? My code is so messy and horrible. I make this mess whenever I am dealing with strings, especially C strings.

Comment: If you have to pass it to the `send()` function, just convert it to a `char const*` _at that point_ (`std::string foo = file_info("file"); send(foo.c_str());`). No need to already do that in `file_info`. The problem of messy code in the presence of C-strings can be easily solved by avoiding C-strings whenever possible.

Comment: Should I avoid C strings? Is it hard to deal with for everyone, even for advanced programmers?

Comment: By the way, my code still fails to give equal spacing length.

Comment: @user2418202 Yes. It makes programs complicated. Use high-level abstractions such as `std::string`.

Comment: @user2418202 it's not unmanageably hard to deal with them, but unnecessary hard. So yes, you should avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your iostream formatting question, you want std::setw

```
std::cout << "'" << std::setw(16) << "Hello" << "'" << std::endl;
```

http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node83.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two different problems. First you obviously can not return `const char *` from function which is stack-allocated. So you have to have it allocated at the heap. And this is the problem. It is problem of ownership. Where you have to `delete` this string? It can be easily solved by using `std::string`.

Second problem is yours question. How to have this well aligned. Using yours method you can not print filenames longer then preallocated string. There si simple solution. In header `iomanip` is defined function

```
/*unspecified*/ std::setw( int n );
```

which say "Hey, next thing you will be printing have to be `n` characters long". And this is what you want. When thing you will be printing is longer then this `n` it will be printed all. No cropping or something like this.

Comment: Can you attach setw(int n) into string, or stringstream, or char* ? I need to make it into a string object, not to output it.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutly have to use null-terminated C-Strings, than rather use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) instead of std::stringstream. Mixing C and C++ like this is considered bad practice (like pointed out already: i.e. you have to manage memory manually). Also there are some other issues with your code: the [sizeof()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) operator doesn't calculate the length of a string - rather the necessary memory-space (in bytes). Returning a reference to the [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/ctime/) internal buffer isn't safe either:

> The function also accesses and modifies a shared internal buffer,
>   which may cause data races on concurrent calls to asctime or ctime

Rather use Call-by-reference and don't return anything. Like this:

```
void file_info(char* file, char* buffer) {
    if(file[0] != '.') {
        struct stat sb;
        if (stat(file, &sb) == -1) {
            perror("stat");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        char* lm = ctime(&sb.st_mtime);
        *lm = '\0';
        sprintf(buffer, "%10s%10s%d", file, lm, sb.st_size);
    }
}
```

To fix your formating problem, you could also use [strlen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) (but not sizeof()) and use whitespaces depending on the length of lm and file. But sprintf provides an fixed length Parameter with %"number of digits"s.

See also: [printf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

> Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed
>   is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces.
>   The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

But you would allocate memory for char* buffer before you call this function and have to make sure, it's large enough for the sprintf string(!).

i.e.

```
char buffer[256];
file_info(file, buffer);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```